# Conditions on mutli-index + data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe that I am grouping to get a multi-index Dataframe:

```
    In[33]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'foo', 5], [0, 'foo', 7], [1, 'foo', 4], [1, 'bar', 5], [1, 'foo', 6], [1, 'bar', 2], [2, 'bar', 3]], columns=['id', 'foobar', 'A'])
In[34]: df
Out[34]: 
   id foobar  A
0   0    foo  5
1   0    foo  7
2   1    foo  4
3   1    bar  5
4   1    foo  6
5   1    bar  2
6   2    bar  3
In[35]: df.groupby(['id', 'foobar']).size()
Out[35]: 
id  foobar
0   foo       2
1   bar       2
    foo       2
2   bar       1
dtype: int64
```

I want to get lines in "id" where number of "foo" >= 2 AND number of "bar" >= 2 so basically get :

```
   foobar  A
id          
1     bar  2
      foo  2
```

But I'm a bit lost about how I should state this conditions with a multi-index ?

edit : this is not a redundant with [How to filter dates on multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876664) since I don't work with dates and I need conditions on the number of particular values in my Dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter dates on multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876664/how-to-filter-dates-on-multiindex-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `all` after `unstack` , then select the one you need , `stack` back

```
new=df.groupby(['id', 'foobar']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
new[new.ge(2).all(1)].stack()
id  foobar
1   bar       2
    foo       2
dtype: int64
```